Reference/Textbook for Nonautonomous discrete dynamical systems
I am interested in a nonautonomous discrete dynamical system where the next value $\mathbf{x}_{t+1}$ is determined by the current value $\mathbf{x}_{t}$ and the current time $t$.
However, I could not find the introductory textbook/reference for that context.
Does anyone have a nice one?

It really depends on what you may be interested and on your former knowledge (say basic knowledge of linear algebra, topology, etc).

Thank you for your comments. I have a basic knowledge of undergraduate-level mathematics including calculus, linear algebra, general topology, differential geometry, and autonomous dynamical systems.

In addition, my interests lie in basic concepts for analyzing nonautonomous systems numerically and analytically, like the linear stability analysis in autonomous systems.

Perhaps then a good choice could be the Hasselblatt-Katok introductory book https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/first-course-in-dynamics/46B75AA48693D96EF48C544A06623247
